# Subtract 1 from all file names (rename them) in a directory.

Tags: command-line, rename

I have a directory which contains image files with names like

```
image1.jpg 
image2.jpg 
image3.jpg
...
```

Unfortunately, the image names must be zero based, so `image1.jpg` should be `image0.jpg`, `image2.jpg` should be `image1.jpg` and so on.

I can write a script to *generate* mv commands like these, put them in a shell script, and then execute them -

```
mv image1.jpg image0.jpg
mv image2.jpg image1.jpg
mv image3.jpg image2.jpg
...
```

But I suppose there is a neater way to do it in Unix. So what is it?

Comment: That's actually the simplest way to do it, as long as there are no gaps. (`for i in $(seq 0 100); do mv image$[i+1].jpg image$i.jpg; done`)

Comment: Is the order of images important? If not, just rename the last image from `imageN.jpg` to `image0.jpg` and you are done.

Comment: @jnovacho, quite clever! But yes, the order of images is important.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The good old perl rename:

```
rename 's/(\d+)(\.jpg)/($1-1).$2/e' *
```

[Remarks]

Image numbers should be greater than 0.

In case images are greater than 9 and have not leading 0s,
use `$(ls -v1 *)` to avoid clobbering. Proposed by @arielf and noticed by @Graeme.

When in doubt use also `-v` for verbose and `-n` for no-action.

Comment: What does the "e" indicate?

Comment: 'e' means evaluate, the replace section will be evaluated. see also `perlreref`

Comment: Files should be passed in ascending order to avoid any clobber. This will work fine only if there are less than 10 files (or if numbers have leading zeros).

Comment: I noticed this already, also there must not be a `0` in the sources.

Comment: replace the `*` at the end with `\`ls -v1 *\`` and you'll be safer from clobbering. It'll go from the lowest number to highest.

Comment: good point, but also out of scope, just imagine `touch image$(perl -e 'print 2 x 245').jpg`

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe the generated `mv` commands to `bash`. So you don't have to copy them in a script and execute that. See:

```
command_that_generates_mv_commands | bash
```

And everything will be executed that is piped to `bash`.

Comment: That is not neater. `:)` Solves the problem though, so +1.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate on ls output, this one works for your example:

```
i=0 
for file in $(ls *.jpg | sort) ; do 
     mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's/[0-9]*.jpg$/'${i}'.jpg/')
     i=$((++i))
done
```

You must be on the same path of your files

Comment: Better to use `-i` or `-n` with `mv`, it will prevent overwriting in edge cases.

Comment: wouldn't `sort -V` be better instead?

Comment: `sort` won't work, it will show `image10.jpg` before `image1.jpg` which might be an issue. You need `sort -nk 1.8` as in @Graeme's answer.

Comment: @user80551, `sort -V` is a good idea, will add it to my answer. There could be other edge cases though, just generally good advice to add these kind of options with questions like this in case someone copies and ends up doing some damage.

Comment: Careful! This solution only works if your numbers are all consecutive (or rather, if you want them to become consecutive, starting from 0).

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to work for anything that fits the pattern `imageNUMBER.jpg`. I've placed `echo` before the `mv` command to first show what the command would do; to actually perform the renaming, just remove the `echo`

```
for i in `ls image*.jpg|sort -V` ; do 
    x=`echo $i|sed -e "s/image\(.*\).jpg/\1/"`
    y=$(( $x - 1 ))
    echo mv -i $i image$y.jpg
done
```

In the first line, the `ls image*.jpg|sort -V` will cause the JPG files to be listed with ascending numbers in the filename. The `x=` line extracts the number from the filename. The `y=` line then decrements the number by one. The input filename and the `y` number are then used in the `mv` command, where the `-i` flag will notify you before overwriting a file.

For my own small test, this produced the output:

```
mv -i image1.jpg image0.jpg
mv -i image2.jpg image1.jpg
mv -i image123.jpg image122.jpg
```

Personally, I'd suggest renaming to a more different filename, since now the order in which the files are processed can make a big difference.

Comment: Better to use `-i` or `-n` with `mv`, it will prevent overwriting in edge cases.

Comment: Very good suggestion, I'll edit the answer

Comment: In macOS, you should use `sort -n`, the `-V` option does't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `perl` script `prename`, which is symlinked to rename on Debian based distros, also needs GNU `find`/`sort`. The files are put in ascending order to prevent any overwriting.

```
find . -regex '\./image[0-9]+\.jpg' -print0 | sort -zV |
  xargs -0 rename -n 's/(\d+)\.jpg$/@{[$1-1]}.jpg/'
```

Remove the `-n` once you are sure it does what you want. Will warn about files already existing before doing so. However as long as it shows the files being renamed in ascending order, there will be no conflicts when run for real.

Comment: File already exists issues with this one.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # (in ~/.zshrc)
zmv -Qf -n 'image(<->).jpg(n)' 'image$(($1-1)).jpg'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

`(n)` is to sort the list numerically so `image9.jpg` is renamed before `image10.jpg`.